# Making File Size visible to anonymous users

Tags: 7, tokens, media, display-suite

I have media installed for file handling, and am displaying download links for my files using display suite.  I have the file size being loaded in as a dynamic field loading token [file:size].

Everything works fine while I'm logged in as admin, but when I view the page as an anonymous user, the file size no longer shows up.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permission should be given for that *file type* in case of anonymous user.

Because if size is visible to authenticated user and not to anonymous user, then it must be a permission issue.